# jQuery Mobile with KnockoutJS ListView Issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

This example of what I am trying, the listview doesn't end up with nice looks,

Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong. this is happening specifically on data-inset=true.

http://jsfiddle.net/xQ9Uu/1/

if I set like this, its ok but its not really the list.

```
<ul id="alarmslist" data-bind="foreach: days" data-role="listview">
```

making the data-inset true breaks the design.

```
 <ul id="alarmslist" data-bind="foreach: days" 
data-inset="true" data-role="listview">
```

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refreshing the list view after update should solve your problem. For that you can use a custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqmRefreshList = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); // make this update fire each time the array is updated.
        $(element).listview("refresh")
    }
};
```

And in the HTML:

```
<ul id="alarmslist" data-bind="foreach: days, jqmRefreshList: days" data-inset="true" data-role="listview">
```

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xQ9Uu/44/